# Temporary prevent drawing while animation is running

Tags: android, animation, drawing, android-imageview

I got a large `ImageView` that covers the entire screen. I made a "slide-in" menu that activates when you press anywhere on the screen, I did that using an animation so it looks like the menu slides in.

Because of the image inside the `ImageView` this causes the animation to stutter. When I leave the `ImageView` empty it goes really smooth.

This is because the image inside the `ImageView` is constantly getting redrawn during the animation, and my android tablet is having a hard time processing it.

I've tried setting `WillNotDraw` to `true` on my `ImageView` and back to `false` when the animation is done, but this results into the image disappearing while the animation plays (smoothly) and then it appears again.

Here is how I create the animation:

```
topMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_down);
slideDown.setStartOffset(200);
topMenu.startAnimation(slideDown);
```

This is the animation xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
   <translate 
       android:fromYDelta="-40" 
       android:toYDelta="0" 
       android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

The image inside the `ImageView` is a done by a `Bitmap`

How can I leave the image visible while an animation is playing, but still maintain that smoothness in the animation?

Comment: How did you create the animation? How are you calling it? This is one of those things that can be done so many different ways that some code is definitely required to help you. Please paste the pertinent code. :)

Comment: You are still missing the code for the animation itself. It looks as if you created it with an XML file? While it may not seem pertinent (and indeed may not be) we won't know unless we see it. You might want to paste that as well. Does this also have a slide_up counterpart? How many animations is this topmenu using?

Answer (score 0):

How about lets say if you are using Animation Listener and look out for the Animation Completion and draw the Image at the end using this,

```
slideDown.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // Draw your Image here

            }
        });
```

Comment: I already tried this, but it makes the image disappear during the animation and just re-appear at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Pieter,

According to your code, you are reloading the animation every time you want to run the animation. You might want to move the animation load itself to a class member rather than a local variable. This will ease ***some*** of the strain. Further details when more information is provided.

Comment: I edited my code but it did not seem to remove any noticeable strain. I will edit my question with more information.